# PHP else if statement can not seem to get the syntax right

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using Dreamweaver. It is telling me something is wrong from line 4, the first else, on. It does not tell me anything useful. What is wrong with my syntax?

```
<title>
<?php //storefront_title(); ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('description'); ?><?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_home() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>  <?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_search() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Search Results<?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_author() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Author Archives<?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_single() ) { ?><?php wp_title(''); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php wp_title(''); ?><?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_category() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php } ?>
<?php else if ( is_month() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php the_time('F'); ?><?php } ?>
<?php else if (function_exists('is_tag')) {
    if ( is_tag() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Tag Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php  single_tag_title("", true); }
    } ?>
</title>
```

Comment: What is wrong with your syntax is that you make it totally hard for yourself to see what is going on in the code. Please just use multiple lines and don't keep opening and closing those php tags.

Comment: My eyes! **The goggles do nothing!** :)

Comment: Why don't you just run it and see what kind of error message php generates?

Comment: ... reaching for my bottle of Excedrin ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<title>
<?php
//storefront_title();
if (is_front_page()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; bloginfo('description');

} else if (is_home()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; bloginfo('description');

} else if (is_search()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Search Results';

} else if (is_author()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Author Archives';

} else if (is_single()) {
    wp_title(''); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; bloginfo('name');

} else if (is_page()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; wp_title('');

} else if (is_category()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; single_cat_title();

} else if (is_month()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;'; the_time('F');

} else if (function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
    bloginfo('name'); echo '&nbsp;|&nbsp;Tag Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;'single_tag_title("", true);

}
?>
</title>
```

Comment: Can you please indicate what you've changed and what improvements were observed?

Answer (score 6):

Ok... so here's an attempt to clean up your syntax:

```
<title>
<?php 
if ( is_front_page() ) { 
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    bloginfo('description');
} elseif ( is_home() ) { 
    bloginfo('name'); 
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    bloginfo('description');
} elseif ( is_search() ) { 
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;Search Results";
} elseif ( is_author() ) { 
    bloginfo('name'); 
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;Author Archives";
} elseif ( is_single() ) { 
    wp_title(''); 
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    bloginfo('name');
} elseif ( is_page() ) { 
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    wp_title('');
} elseif ( is_category() ) { 
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    single_cat_title();
} elseif ( is_month() ) { 
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    the_time('F');
} elseif ( function_exists('is_tag') && is_tag()) {
    bloginfo('name');
    echo "&nbsp;|&nbsp;Tag Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;";
    single_tag_title("", true);
}?>
</title>
```

Phew... after all that, it looks like you can combine some if statements (`is_front_page() || is_home()`).  Without knowing more about what these functions do... (eg do the `bloginfo` functions output content directly?) can't help much more.

Comment: @PeeHaa what do you want super-editor status?  Changing double quotes to single does nothing beneficial.

Comment: @Rudu: It *may* speed it up *slightly*.

Comment: @Rudu: actually as Rocket already stated: `it may speed it up slightly`. So I thought why not make the answer better while we are at it.

Comment: @Rocket /PeeHaa care to back that claim with a benchmark? That concept is based on flawed reasoning (check similar SO answers).  Benchmarking has shown there's no speed/performance difference.

Answer (score 3):

PHPs parser does indeed terminate block level parsing when it encounters `?>`.

For example this is perfectly valid:

```
 if (1)     { 2222; }
 elseif (3) { 4444; }
```

While this leads to an `unexpected T_ELSE` or `ELSEIF`:

```
 if (1)     { 2222; }
 ?><?
 elseif (3) { 4444; }
```

So it's not just a switch between code and raw html.

However it does work with the alternative syntax:

```
 if (1):     { 2222; }
 ?><?
 elseif (3): { 4444; }
 ?><?
 endif;
```

@OP: Note that you should not use this either. Just for weird syntax edge case explanation. Making your code less ugly is the advisable alternative.

Answer (score 2):

```
<title>
<?php //storefront_title(); ?>
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php     bloginfo('description'); ?><?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_home() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>  <?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_search() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Search Results<?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_author() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Author Archives<?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?><?php wp_title(''); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('name'); ?><?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_page() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php wp_title(''); ?><?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_category() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php single_cat_title(); ?><?php }else  ?>
<?php if ( is_month() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php the_time('F'); ?><?php }else  ?>
<?php if (function_exists('is_tag')) {
    if ( is_tag() ) { ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;|&nbsp;Tag Archive&nbsp;|&nbsp;<?php  single_tag_title("", true); }
    } ?>
</title>
```

Comment: Might want to indicate what you changed... lot of code going on here.

Comment: What did you change. I'm trying to see but my eyes keep bleeding. :P

Comment: It seems he added the `else`s to the end of the previous lines, instead at the beginning of the lines.

Comment: Wow, this actually works, see: http://codepad.org/xzpPrmXK (I only did it with the first `else`)